# Load the properties file to get the key value pair

Tags: java, properties

```
PasswordBlurb7=\u4E0D\u53EF\u4F7F\u7528\u91CD\u8907\u5B57\u5143\uFF08\u4F8B\u5982 aaa64135\u3001111bcxjk\uFF09
```

One of my properties file contains the above key=value pair. So when I try to load this key. I  do not get the value. I get ???????? in the value

```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  InputStream in = application.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/classes/content/"+line);
String value;
prop.load(in); 
for(Object str: prop.keySet()) {
            value = prop.getProperty((String) str);
            hashMap.put((String)str, value);

}
```

So in the value I get like this--

```
??????????? aaa64135?111bcxjk?
```

I am outputting like this--

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Key</th>
<th>Values</th>
</tr>
<%
                        for (Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
                                        String key = entry.getKey();
                                        String value = entry.getValue();
%>
<tr><td>
<% out.println(key); %>
</td>
<td>
<% out.println(value);  %>
</td></tr>
<%                                                      }
                        //out.println(hashMap);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {

                        }

%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Anything wrong with my code..

Comment: How are you outputting it?  It's probably stored correctly but you're looking at it wrong.

Comment: You probably use a font which doesn't support the symbols of the password.

Comment: I updated the question for outputting..

Comment: @JBNizet  I was not able to understand. What does font mean here..

Comment: Values are not getting stored correctly too. I check by printing the value.

Comment: font means... font (as in Arial, Times New Roman, etc.). It might also be an encoding problem. If the HTML page uses ASCII or ISO-8859-1, all these chars are not supported by this encoding. Make sure to use a no-loss encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: How can I use encoding like UTF-8 as I am using JSP to display the values into the Browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is a string containing unicode-escaped characters. The reason you see `?????...` is most likely that the output device you are using does not handle unicode, or that it is using a font that does not contain these asian symbols:

```
\u4E0D\u53EF\u4F7F\u7528\u91CD\u8907\u5B57\u5143\uFF08\u4F8B\u5982 aaa64135\u3001111bcxjk\uFF09 

不可使用重複兇元（例如aaa64135、111bcxjk）
```

Comment: I am outputting that value to Browser using JSP. So how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Make sure you get the encoding right, and that you tell the browser what encoding you are using. What is your `Content-Type`?

Comment: If I am using this <%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %> then I get in the value as--  ` 不可使用重複字元（例如 aaa64135、111bcxjk） `

Comment: That should do the trick, yes. The default was possibly `us-ascii` or `iso-8859-1`, encodings that does not the password characters.

Comment: But I am not getting this value `\u4E0D\u53EF\u4F7F\u7528\u91CD\u8907\u5B57\u5143\uFF08\u4F8B\u5982 aaa64135\u3001111bcxjk\uFF09` I am getting some chinese characters. I want that value only.

Comment: The value _is_ a unicode string. If you want `\u4E0D\u53EF..`, the value would have to be `\\u4E0D\\u53EF..`, or you would have to escape the string before you `out.println` it.